# Postgresql command execution in bash script

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell

I have written a shell script to execute postgresql commands . Problem is when I am executing this script it is showing an error :  `line 17: psql: command not found`

my script is as follows:

```
export PGPASSWORD=${PGPASSWORD-my_password}
echo "enter host"
read host
echo "enter database name"
read dbname
echo "enter username"
read username
psql -h $host $dbname $username <<EOF
SELECT * FROM test ; >>res.txt
EOF

( cat res.txt) | sed 's/;/<tab>/g' > $file.csv
rm res.txt
unset PGPASSWORD
```

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong .

Comment: Isn't it telling you the problem: `line 17: psql: command not found`?  You need to either specify the complete path to `psql` or install it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @devnull . but i have already installed psql

Comment: @DEVANGPANDEY can you show us the output for `whereis psql` ?

Comment: @devangpandey You need to add it to the `PATH` as well.  Try issuing `psql` from the command line; you'll figure.

Comment: @devnull In that case is my shell script correct?

Comment: @DEVANGPANDEY *mostly*, yes.  I'm not sure if you want `>>`, you probably wanted to say `>` instead.  You need to read about redirection.

Comment: What operating system are you on *exactly*? And how'd you install PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate your psql binary with

```
which psql
```

you will get output like

```
/usr/bin/psql
```

Now you can use the complete path in your script or extend your $PATH

Just a short note! Don't save your password within the script. If you need the (psql) password for certain users you should save it in .pgpass

```
host:db:user:password
```

and give it the proper permission (i.e. 0600)